# Duda con clase Graphics sobre sus métodos abstractos, ¿por qué funcionan si son abstractos y no tienen cuerpo?

Tags: java, java-swing

```
public void paintComponents(Graphics g){
    g.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);
}
```

¿por qué se puede usar este método de la clase `Graphics` si `drawArc` es un método abstracto que no tiene cuerpo? ¿por qué dibuja un arco?

Comment: Y así es como se topa uno con la maravilla que es AWT, felicidades! :D

Answer (score 1):

Si depuras el método vas a ver que en `g` recibes **un objeto cuya clase  hereda de la clase `Graphics`**.

Ese objeto es de una clase concreta (no abstracta), por lo que si que puede llamar al método `drawArc`

En mi caso depurándolo obtengo un objeto de la clase `SunGraphics2D`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Fíjate que esa clase hereda de `Graphics2D` y ésta a su vez hereda de `Graphics`; es concreta e implementa el método `drawArc`:

- https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/java2d/SunGraphics2D.java

```
public final class SunGraphics2D
  extends Graphics2D
  implements ConstrainableGraphics, Cloneable, DestSurfaceProvider
```

Comment: @SantiagoSalinas justo lo estaba editando, pero esa es la clase que sale en mi caso, con mi máquina virtual de java, en tu caso podría ser igual o distinto. Si depuras tu programa vas a poder ver cual clase es exactamente.

Comment: entonces cuando se pide  por parametro una variable de tipo Graphics entonces se estaria  acudiendo a esta clase concreta que me comentas?

Comment: @SantiagoSalinas no es exactamente así. El método `paintComponent` es especial en el sentido de que tú no llamas a ese método, sino que es swing quien internamente le llama cuando necesita saber cómo repintar el componente. Swing internamente tiene un objeto de alguna clase que herede de Graphics. Es decir en alguna parte habrá hecho algo así `Graphics g = new SunGraphics2D()`. Cuando llame a tu método lo hará así `component.paintComponents(g);` A ti te da igual como haya creado `g`, lo que sabes es que vas a recibir un objeto que hereda de `Graphics` y puedes usar todos sus métodos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias amigo,era una duda que me comia la cabeza,abrazo!

Answer (score -1):

El argumento **g** pertenece a la clase *SunGraphics2d* y esta hereda de la clase *Graphics*.

Y ahora la clase *SunGraphics2D* esta dentro de nuestra libreria *JRE*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego ingresa a **rt** y encontramos la clase *SunGraphics2D*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]